# How to learn if two `std::multimap`s have the same contents?

Tags: c++, stl, multimap

I have to admit I've never made a proper study of the standard library, but this caught me by surprise

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
    std::multimap<int, int> mm1;
    mm1.insert( std::pair<int, int>(0, 0) );
    mm1.insert( std::pair<int, int>(0, 1) );

    std::multimap<int, int> mm2;
    mm2.insert( std::pair<int, int>(0, 1) );
    mm2.insert( std::pair<int, int>(0, 0) );

    std::cout << "The maps are "
          << ( (mm1 == mm2) ? "equal" : "not equal" )
          << std::endl;
}
```

And trying it we get ...

```
$ g++ --std=c++11 -o multimaporder multimaporder.cc
$ ./multimaporder 
The maps are not equal
```

So, the order you put things into the map matters. That would not have been my first expectation for an associative container, but fine.

With a random access container my next plan would usually be to sort them and then compare ... but adding

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
    std::sort( mm1.begin(), mm1.end() );
    std::sort( mm2.begin(), mm2.end() );

    std::cout << "The *sorted* maps are "
              << ( (mm1 == mm2) ? "equal" : "not equal" )
              << std::endl;
```

just results is a lot of complaints about not finding an acceptable set of iterators to hand to `sort`.

So what is the right way to find out if two `multimap`s have the same contents?

Comment: maybe you should use `std::set<std::pair<int, int>>`

Comment: Or perhaps `std::map<int, std::set<int>>`.

Comment: In this case the need to test for equality of contents only comes up in my tests (round-tripping some (de-)serialization code), and I can work around that by inserting the test data in the order that will work. By the issue has tickled my curiosity bump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case, you need to compare the sets like below

```
bool comp ()
{
    using Map = std::multimap<int, int>;
    Map mm1;
    mm1.insert( std::pair<int, int>(0, 0) );
    mm1.insert( std::pair<int, int>(0, 1) );

    Map mm2;
    mm2.insert( std::pair<int, int>(0, 1) );
    mm2.insert( std::pair<int, int>(0, 0) );


    return std::set<Map::value_type>(mm1.begin(), mm1.end()) == std::set<Map::value_type>(mm2.begin(), mm2.end());
}
```

Comment: It may work in particular situation but wrong solution in general - multimap allows duplicates but set does not.

Comment: Using `std::multiset` instead gets this working again for that case. Though the user needs to think carefully about what they want. Adding (0, 0) (0, 1) (0, 1) to one multimap and (0, 0) (0, 1) to the other compares equal using `std::set` and unequal using `std::multiset`.

Comment: In any case I find this scheme clear and I think it runs in in `n log n` time, which is not great but doesn't have the scary worst case that comes with using `unordered_multimap`.

Answer (score 2):

> So, the order you put things into the map matters.

No it does not matter for the map, but you use multimap, which is a different beast. As stated in documentation for [`std::multimap::insert()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/insert)

> 1-2) inserts value. **If the container has elements with equivalent key, inserts at the upper bound of that range.(since C++11)** The overload (2) is equivalent to emplace(std::forward
>
> (value)) and only participates in overload resolution if std::is_constructible::value == true.

emphasis is mine. So possible solutions:

- insert values into `std::multimap` to keep them in the same order in both containers (for example sorted) by providing proper hint to `std::multimap::insert`.
- use container where all pairs fully sorted for example `std::set<std::pair<int,int>>` you should be aware of difference in behavior
- use special comparator, which would somehow realize if values in different order are equal

Note you cannot resort elements in `std::multimap` passing it's iterators to `std::sort`, that would break container invariant.

Answer (score 1):

Per [[associative.reqmts]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/associative.reqmts#4) `std::multimap` requires that the order of insertion for equivalent keys is maintained so two containers will only compare equal if they have the same values in the same order.

If you don't care about the order you can use a `std::unordered_multimap` which doesn't not care about the order and will compare equal to each other as long as they have the same values

```
int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
    std::unordered_multimap<int, int> mm1;
    mm1.insert( std::pair<int, int>(0, 0) );
    mm1.insert( std::pair<int, int>(0, 1) );

    std::unordered_multimap<int, int> mm2;
    mm2.insert( std::pair<int, int>(0, 1) );
    mm2.insert( std::pair<int, int>(0, 0) );

    std::cout << "The maps are "
          << ( (mm1 == mm2) ? "equal" : "not equal" )
          << std::endl;
}
```

Outputs

```
The maps are equal
```

Comment: Hmm not sure if it is valid to use unordered_multimap in this case "The iteration order of this container is not required to be stable (so, **for example, std::equal cannot be used to compare two std::unordered_multimaps**), except that every group of elements whose keys compare equivalent (compare equal with key_eq() as the comparator) forms a contiguous subrange in the iteration order, also accessible with equal_range()."

Comment: @Slava It doesn't work with `std::equal`, but `operator==` is required to work: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/unord.req#12

Comment: I see, did not know that `st::equal` is different than `==`, but O(N^2) ouch.